# How to Monitor SheetChange in VBA across a range and not just on a cell with a dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I am after creating a dropdown on cells in a column. When one particular option is selected I would like to do some actions. I can do this on one cell but not on a column of cells. So I wish to change to this on the range.

```
Select Case Range("I6:I1000")
```

Can this be done? If I do this then I get a "VBA Type Mismatch Error". Really hope you can help. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Select Case Range(“I6”)

Case “7 - engaged”
VBA.Interaction.MsgBox “Client Status selected as engaged. Confirm to post to tank.”, 1,  “Status Change”

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: `Target` is the range that was changed, which presumably is what you should be looking at in your code.

Comment: Adding to what @Rory said, have a look at `Intersect`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to loop through each cell in the range (assuming you need to check the value in cells other than the one just changed):

```
Dim myRange as Range

For each myRange in Range("I6:I1000")
Select Case myRange.value
    Case "7 - engaged"
        ...
        ...
End Select
```